# How to get build to fail when running bcp from an msbuild script?

Tags: sql-server-2005, msbuild, bcp

As part of sql server 2005, there is the bulk copy command "bcp.exe" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

We are running the bcp command from our msbuild script using the exec task.  Unfortunately, when bcp fails to load a row of data, the build still succeeds.

I tried (per build script snippet below) specifying an error file, and checking for its existence, unfortunately that means the build always fails even if bcp completely succeeds, because it appears that bcp will always create the error file even if there are no errors.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <bcpFiles Include="$(DataPath)\*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
<Delete Files="BcpErrors.txt" />
<Message Text="bcp $(DatabaseName).dbo.%(bcpFiles.FileName) in %(bcpFiles.FullPath) -eBcpErrors.txt -c -E -q -t&quot;`&quot; -r&quot;`\n&quot; $(bcpConnectionString)" />
<Exec Command="bcp $(DatabaseName).dbo.%(bcpFiles.FileName) in %(bcpFiles.FullPath) -eBcpErrors.txt -c -E -q -t&quot;`&quot; -r&quot;`\n&quot; $(bcpConnectionString)" />
<Error Condition="Exists('BcpErrors.txt')" Text="One or more bcp commands contained errors." />
```

Is there any way I can get msbuild to fail the build if bcp fails to load any of the data?

Comment: Does BCP produce any deterministic output when it fails?

Comment: It produces error text on the Console, and information on the number of rows copied on the console, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it's not exactly using bcp.exe, but BULK INSERT is very similar to bcp.exe, can take the same format of files, and has most of the same options.  The Sql.Execute task will also fail if the BulkInsert query fails. So I ended up with

```
<ItemGroup>
  <bcpFiles Include="$(DataPath)\*.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
<Sql.Execute ConnectionString="$(ConnectionString)" Sql="BULK INSERT [$(DatabaseName)].dbo.[%(bcpFiles.FileName)] FROM '%(bcpFiles.FullPath)' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char', KEEPIDENTITY, FIELDTERMINATOR='`', ROWTERMINATOR='`\n', MAXERRORS=1)" />
```

(Sql.Execute task is defined in Microsoft.Sdc.Common.tasks)

Answer (score 0):

If BCP returns a non-zero error code for failure then the MSBuild Exec task should detect that and mark the task as failed.

Comment: Apparently BCP is not returning a non-zero code, unless you can see something that I did wrong on the msbuild code in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. Personally, I wouldn't fail the build on a staging step.

Comment: I do need the build to fail.  With this data, if it isn't copied in, then the environment will fail to work correctly. I don't want to hand off a bad environment to the test team.

Comment: @Nathan - I don't know your environment, but I'd expect QA to have their own process for prepping the environment to fit their test cases. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MSBuild ExtensionPack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) "File" task to look for error text in the output file:

```
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="FilterByContent" RegexPattern="Error = " Files="BcpErrors.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="IncludedFileCount" PropertyName="ErrorFileCount"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File>        
    <Error Condition="$(ErrorFileCount) != 0" Text="One or more bcp commands contained errors." />
```

Comment: unfortunately, the error file appears to also be empty most of the time.

Comment: Oh... so do you get an error response to the console but not to  "BcpErrors.txt"?

Comment: Yep, I get the errors on the console, but not in the error file.

Comment: It's probably a bit late for this since you have a solution now, but you could try and send the output to a file in your Exec command with the ">" character, e.g. 
`<Exec Command="bcp $(DatabaseName).dbo.%(bcpFiles.FileName) in %(bcpFiles.FullPath) -eBcpErrors.txt -c -E -q -t&quot;`&quot; -r&quot;`\n&quot; $(bcpConnectionString) > CmdErrors.txt" />`